# How to use method with Predicate parameter, without using lambda expression

Tags: java, collections, predicate

I am working on a Post Office Storage exercise, where some of the methods are using another method `searchBoxes` whose parameter is a Predicate. I have to implement those methods using `searchBoxes`, but I must not use a lambda expression like I already do.

This is the `searchBoxes` method I have to use:

```
public List<Box> searchBoxes(Predicate<Box> predicate) {
    if(predicate == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    List<Box> selected = new LinkedList<>();
    for(Box box : parcels) {
        if(predicate.test(box)) {
            selected.add(box);
        }
    }
    return selected;
}
```

And this is one of the other methods:

```
public List<Box> getAllWeightLessThan(double weight) {
    if(weight < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    List<Box> result = searchBoxes(e -> e.getWeight() < weight);
    return result;
}
```

What I have to do is to avoid the lambda expression where I call the `searchBoxes` method: `searchBoxes(e -> e.getWeight() < weight);`, but the problem is that I must use the `searchBoxes` method.

How is it possible to avoid this and call the method in same way but without a lambda?

Comment: like this ? `searchBoxes(new Predicate<Box>{@Override public boolean test(Box box){return e.getWeight() < weight; }});`

Comment: `Predicate` is an interface. Did you look up how to implement an interface?

Comment: @JaggerCai Yess, its working but with little changes. Thats what i tried unsuccessfuly to do. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: for my understanding, any specific reason why you would want to avoid using the lambda expression there?

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj Thats the purpose of the exercise. I have restrictions that I must comply with. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a normal implementation:

```
public class MaxWeightPredicate implements Predicate<Box> {
  
  private final double maxWeight;

  public MaxWeightPredicate(double maxWeight) {
    this.maxWeight = maxWeight;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean test(Box box) {
    return box.getWeight() < this.maxWeight;
  }
}
```

And usage:

```
List<Box> result = searchBoxes(new MaxWeightPredicate(weight));
```

Or use anonymous class, but you have to declare it in a place with access to `weight`:

```
Predicate<Box> predicate = new Predicate<Box>() {
  @Override
  public boolean test(Box box) {
    return box.getWeight() < weight;
  }
};
```

Comment: Exactly the anonymous class is what I was trying, but in a wrong way. It works perfect. Thank you! :)